# Hide soft keyboard on pressing back

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-manifest, android-softkeyboard

I have an `EditText` in an `Activity` and I want it to be active and soft-keyboard be open when I open that `Activity`. Here is my `xml` for `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    android:background="@null"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:elegantTextHeight="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:id="@+id/editText11"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapSentences"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
```

and I have used `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` for the activity in which I have this `EditText`.

The problem is, when I press `back` once, the keyboard does not hide(ideally it does in all other `EditText`s) and when I press `back` again, it closes the `Activity`. On the first `back` press, I am **not** getting a call to `onBackPressed()` while on the second `back` press, I do. Why is this kind of behaviour is happening and how to resolve it?

**Edit** What I want is, if keyboard is open, pressing back should close the keyboard and if the keyboard is not open, then close the activity.

Comment: I Update my answer create a sample project try to understand then Implement in your main Project.

Comment: @Harshad Ok, I will try that and let you know.

Answer (score 14):

Try this ...

**create class called Util and put this code**

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputMethodManager.isActive()) {
        if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**and call on the onBackPressed() of Activity**

Answer (score 5):

I add below code in my BaseActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputMethodManager != null && inputMethodManager.isActive()) {
        if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                 //useful for hiding the soft-keyboard is:
                 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

This may helps you

Answer (score 0):

**As Your Requirement** :

> if keyboard is open, pressing back should close the keyboard and if
>   the keyboard is not open, then close the activity

I Have tested my code is work fine.

**Step 1 :** Create `CustomEditText` like below.

```
 <com.yourpackage.yourappname.CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Step 2 :** Create `CustomEditText.java` class.

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

    Context context;
    private static Activity mSearchActivity;;

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {
        if(mSearchActivity != null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            KeyEvent.DispatcherState state = getKeyDispatcherState();

            if(state != null){
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){

                    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)
                            context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                else if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && !event.isCanceled() && state.isTracking(event)){
                    mSearchActivity.onBackPressed();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }


        return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
    }    

}
```

**Step 3 :** In Your Activity intialize the CustomEditText and hide KeyBoard like below.

```
CustomEditText editText = (CustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

**Step 4:** In Your Activity simply `Override` the `onBackPressed()` method.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
```

Comment: I don't want to hide the soft keyboard and close the activity at once. What I want is, if keyboard is open, pressing back should close the keyboard and if the keyboard is not open, then close the activity.

Comment: @AmitTiwari see Update my answer.

Comment: From where do I call this function?

Comment: @AmitTiwari simply you have to Override .

Comment: @AmitTiwari see my full answer.

Comment: when I `@Override` this method, I get an error that `Method does not override method from its superclass`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111411/discussion-between-harshad-and-amit-tiwari).

Comment: how does the `CustomEditText` get reference to `mSearchActivity` ?

Comment: @AmitTiwari you do not need it just define `Activity` is I declare it will automatically take.

Comment: @AmitTiwari go to discussion in chat.